# Codeigniter Query Builder Update function

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I have an update function in my Model which I call from My controller as

```
if($_POST)
{
   $this->User_model->update('user_about',$_POST,$this->session->userdata['id']);
}
```

takes three parameters, table name, post data and user id. The function is defined in the Model as

```
public function update($table,$data,$id)
{
    $row=$this->db->select('*')->from($table)->WHERE('user_id',$id)->row();
    if($row)
    {
        $this->db->WHERE('user_id',$id)->UPDATE($table,$data);
    }
    else
    {
        $data['user_id']=$id;
        $this->db->insert($table,$data);
    }
}
```

What I am doing here is checking if the record of particular user doesn't exist it should insert, otherwise update. Works like a charm

**Question**

Is there a way to skip the IF condition block?. Is there any provision in query builder which performs the check itself?

Comment: only with mysql you can use `INSERT ..  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, but codeigniter does not support such query. write query by yourself. Or extend the query builder class adnd write such method

Comment: @splash58 thats what m doing and its working. just wanted to ask if someone else came across this issue and have the same thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a  custom generic insert and update on duplicate function that I always used in my programming.

```
public function updateOnDuplicate($table, $data ) 
   {
     if (empty($table) || empty($data)) return false;
     $duplicate_data = array();

     foreach($data AS $key => $value) {
        $duplicate_data[] = sprintf("%s='%s'", $key, $value);
     }

     $sql = sprintf("%s ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE %s", $this->db->insert_string($table, $data), implode(',', $duplicate_data));

     $this->db->query($sql);
     return $this->db->insert_id();
   }
```

You can use the above function in the model and call it in the controller. The function will update the value if the duplicate occurs. Check out following blog post if you need detail explanation [A Generic CodeIgniter Function for both Update and Insert](https://shareurcodes.com/blog/a%20generic%20codeIgniter%20function%20for%20both%20update%20and%20insert).

Comment: Excellent code James. I will use it in my project thanks